# Is libspotify available as a plugin for any mobile cross-platform SDK?

Tags: mobile, plugins, cross-platform, spotify, libspotify

Is libspotify available as a plugin for any cross-platform SDK? I'm talking about a native plugin for mobile SDKs like Phonegap, Gideros Mobile, Corona, Intel XDK, Marmalade or similar.

Comment: Why the downvote? Phonegap, for example, provides native plugins for Facebook, push messaging, barcode scanning, etc (build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins). It would be perfectly possible for such a plugin to implement the libspotify API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libspotify is a C library compiled for various targets (Mac, Windows, iOS, Android and various Linux variants), so there's no single cross-platform build.

However, it should be possible to create a wrapper around libspotify in these SDKs and deploy them along with the pre-built binaries to the platforms libspotify supports. There's nothing official like this, though.

Comment: Phonegap, for example, provides native plugins for Facebook, push messaging, barcode scanning, etc (https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins). Hopefully a Spotify plugin next.